# Select query with filter at least one match

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table which I'm trying to select data from using MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id_location`, `id_sector`, `id_group`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 3, 3),
(5, 2, 4),
(6, 3, 4),
(7, 2, 5),
(8, 1, 5),
```

I want to select the rows where `id_sector = 1` but I also need to return any row with the same group value as returned by the query. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id_sector` = `1`
```

would return rows `id_location` 1, 2, 3 and 8 but I would be missing rows with `id_location` 4 and 7, which I need because there have the same `id_group` (3 and 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get a distinct list of id_groups that correspond to your selected id_sector and then query according to that list:

```html
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id_group` IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT `id_group` FROM `test` WHERE `id_sector` = 1)
```